# METAPOST (mptopdf) complains: can't open file `mp-tool'

Tags: metapost

I just did a clean install of Mountain Lion and MacTeX 2012. Now I can't compile my .mp files anymore using the "mptopdf" Terminal command. This is the output I get:

```
MPtoPDF 1.4.1 : running 'mpost --mem=mpost   --tex=latex  test.mp'
This is MetaPost, version 1.504 (kpathsea version 6.1.0)
(mpost.mp (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/metapost/base/plain.mp
Preloading the plain mem file, version 1.004)) (./test.mp
! I can't open file `mp-tool'.
l.6 input mp-tool
                 ;
Please type another input file name:
```

Any ideas on what I can do to make my files compile again?

Everything was working fine two days ago on my Lion.

By the way, here is my `test.mp` file (which I (try to) compile with `mptopdf test.mp`):

```
verbatimtex
%%&latex
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\begin{document}
etex
input mp-tool;
beginfig(0);
draw (0,0)--(10,10);
endfig;
verbatimtex
\end{document}
etex
end
```

**UPDATE:** Interestingly, after installing the older MacTeX 2010 the problem is no longer present. So I'll just use this older version for now. Feel free to post any thoughts, in case you know what went wrong with the latest version.

Comment: In TeX Live 2011 the file you need is `/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/metapost/context/base/mp-tool.mp`. I don't have a 2012 distribution right now.

Comment: @egreg Yes, that's indeed the file that exists in TeX Live 2010 and 2011. Feel free to reply when you ever upgrade to 2012.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, changing

```
input mp-tool;
```

to

```
input mp-tool.mpii;
```

did the trick.